# What is the significance of this painting?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

The Walking Dead Season One, there's a painting spotted in two locations:

Once in Episode 2:

[image]

And once again (though cropped and mirrored) in Episode 4:

[image]

The first time, the painting is just scenery, but the second time the painting can be interacted with and viewed close-up.

What's the significance of this painting?

Comment: Interesting, personally I'd say asset re-use, but I'd love to know if there is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on its location in the game (inside the St. John household), it seems to be a subtle hint at the true nature of the family.

> Since the St. Johns cannibalize people in order to survive.

[This comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheWalkingDeadGame/comments/1zu1gd/hidden_things_in_the_walking_dead_big_spoilers/cfxsd4u/?) actually points out that there is a second painting in their house that is also foreshadowing the rest of the episode:

> Some hidden things I found were paintings in the house of the St. Johns. One depicts the last supper of Jesus (Last supper, heh)

I'm not quite sure about its significance in Episode 4, though. The ability to interact with it is especially confusing.

Comment: When I first saw I was able to interact with it in Episode 4, I immediately drew a parallel. But when that didn't pan out, I was confused.

Comment: @Koviko what's even stranger is that I can't find any mention of it for its appearance in Ep 4, only Ep 2. Being an interactible object, you'd think it'd be mentioned *somewhere*...